# Synchronization using object lock in java

Tags: java, concurrency, object, synchronization

I have two threads thread1(printing numbers) & thread2(printing alphabets).
My goal is to have the following output via syncronization:

> 1
>   a
>   2
>   b
>   3
>   c
>   4
>   d
>   5
>   e

```
class thread1 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {

        try {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Is Thread1 holding lock of Testing.class?:"+Thread.holdsLock(Testing.class));
                synchronized (Testing.class) {
                    System.out.println("Is Thread1 holding lock of Testing.class?:"+Thread.holdsLock(Testing.class));

                    try {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        Testing.class.notifyAll();
                        System.out.println("Thread1:Going to wait");
                        Testing.class.wait();
                        System.out.println("Thread1:Resuming from wait");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

            System.out.println("Finsihed thread1");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}



class thread2 implements Runnable {
    char[] alphabets = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };

    public void run() {

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Is Thread2 holding lock of Testing.class?:"+Thread.holdsLock(Testing.class));
                synchronized (Testing.class) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Is Thread2 holding lock of Testing.class?:"+Thread.holdsLock(Testing.class));
                        System.out.println("Thread2:Going to wait");
                        Testing.class.wait();
                        System.out.println("Thread2:Resuming from wait");
                        System.out.println(alphabets[i]);
                        Testing.class.notifyAll();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}


    public class Testing {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Testing w= new Testing();
            thread1 t1 = new thread1();
            thread2 t2 = new thread2();
            Thread th1 = new Thread(t1, "");

            Thread th2 = new Thread(t2, "");
            try {
                th1.start();
                th2.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    }
```

I am getting the output:

> Is Thread1 holding lock of
>   Testing.class?:false
>
> Is Thread1 holding lock of
>   Testing.class?:true
>
> 1
>
> Thread1:Going to wait
>
> Is Thread2 holding lock of
>   Testing.class?:false
>
> Is Thread2 holding lock of
>   Testing.class?:true
>
> Thread2:Going to wait

How did thread2 got hold the lock of Testing.class when it was already locked by thread1?. Also, Is there any other elegant way to achieve this sync?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem you have is that you release the synchronized block allowing both threads to go through the loop at the same time. This means either thread can obtain the lock in any order.

AFAIK, The simplest solution is to use a flag.

```
final int length = 10;
final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i=1;i<=length;i++) {
            while(flag.get());
            System.out.print(i+" ");
            flag.set(true);
        }
    }
}).start();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (char c='a';c<'a'+length;c++) {
            while(!flag.get());
            System.out.print(c+" ");
            flag.set(false);
        }
       System.out.println();
    }
}).start();
```

The most elegant way to have this task done in sync is to have one thread. Threads are specificly designed to execute two tasks with as little dependence as possible between them.

BTW

If notifyAll() is called before wait() is called, the notify will be lost. wait() will wait forever.

You create a Testing object you discard (remove it).

You trap InterruptedException which you print and continue as if nothing happened (i.e. remove the nested catch)

Comment: Thanks!. I understand that this problem doesn't require threads. But I am just trying to understand/write proper thread synchronization from this code. Sometimes threads do have to depend on execution of another thread http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Read a bit more about [Java Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Calling `wait` releases the lock.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `wait()` method, the thread that you call it in is temporarily giving up the lock. So while thread1 is waiting inside the `wait()` method, it is not holding the lock, and thread2 can get the lock.

When the `wait()` method returns, the thread will hold the lock again.

The API documentation of the `wait()` method in class `Object` explains this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete working code

public class MyClass

{

MyClass mClass;

public void doTest()

{

```
  final  int [] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  final  char [] c = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
   mClass = this; 
   Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

     public void run()
     {
        for(int i = 0 ; i<a.length ; i++)
        {
         synchronized(mClass)
         {
           System.out.print(a[i]+" "); 
           mClass.notify();
           try{mClass.wait();}catch(Exception e){}

         }

        }

     }

   });    
   t1.start();
   Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

     public void run()
     {
        for(int i = 0 ; i<c.length ; i++)
        {synchronized(mClass)
         {
           System.out.print(c[i]+" "); 
           mClass.notify();
             try{mClass.wait();}catch(Exception e){}
         }

        }

     }

   });    
   t2.start();
```

}
   public static void main(String [] ar)
    {

```
  new MyClass().doTest();
}
```

}

Comment: See my comments about ignoring exceptions. BTW, you have no guarantee that t1 will start before t2 and the format is shocking. ;)

Comment: Just maintain a boolean, let me edit it more to assure this result

Comment: I initially had this code to start with. But this resulted in one of the threads ending up waiting forever. Anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: check the new answer now.. now no waiting and first thread will run first for sure.... Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

public class MyClass
{
   MyClass mClass;
   boolean isFirstStartedRunning = true;
   public void doTest()
   {
      final  int [] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
      final  char [] c = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
       mClass = this; 
       Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

```
     public void run()
     {
        isFirstStartedRunning = false;
        for(int i = 0 ; i<a.length ; i++)
        {
         synchronized(mClass)
         {
           System.out.print(a[i]+" "); 
           mClass.notify();
            if(i==a.length-1)return;

             try{mClass.wait();}catch(Exception e){}


         }

        }

     }

   });    
   t1.start();
   Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

     public void run()
     {
        if(isFirstStartedRunning){
          try{mClass.wait();}catch(Exception e){}
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i<c.length ; i++)
        {
         synchronized(mClass)
         {
           System.out.print(c[i]+" "); 
           mClass.notify();
           if(i==a.length-1)return;
           try{mClass.wait();}catch(Exception e){}


         }

       }

     }

   });    
   t2.start();
```

}
   public static void main(String [] ar)
    {

```
  new MyClass().doTest();

}
```

}
check the answer now